# Does ssl block imgur from getting image dimensions?

Tags: php, ssl, gd, imgur

I'm using php GD library to create an png file, I'm saving it to my server.

URL for the image is

https://server.com/signature/123.png

My problem is I can't upload that image to imgur, I get this error

[image]

This issue also occurs on other image uploading sites / forums

However if I decide to download the image to my desktop and upload it to imgur it seems to work. Anyone has an idea on why this is happening?

Comment: You're going to need to show how you're uploading the file.

Comment: Manual upload, copying the url into imgur